# What will be STRING_SPLIT function alternative in DataSet SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

> DataSet:dsStudent (It's a DropDown in the Report)

```
DECLARE @gid VARCHAR(36) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), NEWID());

SELECT CAST(StudentId AS VARCHAR(MAX))+@gid AS StudentId, StudentName
FROM dbo.Student1;
```

> DataSet:dsStudentFilter (Use to Capture data selected from DropDown)

```
SELECT StudentName
FROM Student1
WHERE StudentId IN
      (
          SELECT REPLACE(b.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), RIGHT(b.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 36), '')
          FROM
          (
              VALUES
                  (CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@StudentId, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
          ) A (a)
              CROSS APPLY a.nodes('/x') B(b)
      );
```

Now, when I preview the report I am getting below error:

[image]

Report Design:

[image]

In dsStudentFilter DataSet of SSRS report I want to do something like below:

```
DECLARE @StudentId VARCHAR(MAX)
= '1111112EE300718-79A4-4260-A5E9-22B7CA71998,1111122EE300718-79A4-4260-A5E9-22B7CA71998';
SELECT StudentName
FROM Student1
WHERE StudentId IN
  (
      SELECT value
      FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(@StudentId, RIGHT(@StudentId, 36), ''), ',')
  );
```

But I cannot use STRING_SPLIT in DataSet is there any alternative to do so?

Data in the table:

[image]

Above query will display Jay and Sam.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to do so, you can create an *inline table valued function* on the SQL-Server. Another chance was to use a stored procedure and create the `IN`-clause within dyanmic SQL...

Or you can use this approach for inline splitting:

```
DECLARE @StudentId VARCHAR(MAX) = '3,5,6,7';

SELECT o.*
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.object_id IN
  (
      SELECT b.value('text()[1]','int')
      FROM (VALUES(CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@StudentId,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)))A(a)
      CROSS APPLY a.nodes('/x') B(b)
  );
```

The value list is transfered from `3,5,6,7` to `<x>3</x><x>5</x><x>6</x><x>7</x>` and then handled as XML...

### Hint:

For your example you will have to use `uniqueidentifier` instead of `int` within `.value()`

Comment: I am getting this error while previewing the report "An error occurred during local report processing. An error has occurred during report processing. Query execution failed for dataset 'dsStudentFilter'. The replace function requires 3 arguments(s)

Comment: @JayDesai, show your code... In my example there are 3 arguments: `@StudentId`, `','` (a comma) and `'</x><x>'` (the replacement)... You must have changed something...

Comment: DECLARE @StudentId VARCHAR(MAX)
    = '291540054631905-414A-4669-A941-E21ACB3C0912,291766154631905-414A-4669-A941-E21ACB3C0912';
SELECT b.value('text()[1]', 'uniqueidentifier')
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@StudentId, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))
) A (a)
    CROSS APPLY a.nodes('/x') B(b);
Ran above code getting this error Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @JayDesai This is, because your values aren't GUIDs... Try it with `nvarchar(max) `

Comment: @Shnugo Updated with more explanation.

Comment: @JayDesai The code as provided should not produce the reported error... What are you doing with this concatenated `id + GUID` approach? Are your IDs always exactly 6 digits? Are you allowed to create a function on the server?

Comment: @Shnugo This is just a POC. I was trying to achieve this https://bpmsbi.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/ functionality. Yes IDs will be always 6 digits. No, I am not allowed to create function on server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround:

```
DECLARE @StudentId VARCHAR(MAX)
= '291540054631905-414A-4669-A941-E21ACB3C0912,291766154631905-414A-4669-A941-E21ACB3C0912';

SELECT StudentName
FROM Student
WHERE ',' + @StudentId + ',' LIKE '%,' + StudentId + ',%';
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to search for a given `StudentId` directly in the input string, separated by commas on both sides.  We add commas to the very start and end of the input string before comparing to ensure that every `StudentId` in fact is always separated by commas.

Comment: This will make the index on StudentId unusable

Comment: @OgrishMan A good point, but a somewhat moot one IMHO.  The best thing to do here is to not work with CSV data unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Regrettfully SSRS deals with list-data in CSV strings by default... AFAIK there's no way around...